# How to read splunk webhook payload from post request?

Tags: webhooks, splunk

I am trying to get the JSON payload from post request using Splunk webhook as an alert action. My webhook url is `http://hostname/api/splunk_alert`

My nodejs server listening post request

```
app.post('/api/splunk_alert', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
     response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});
```

Can someone please let me know if I am in right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, its looking OK so far. Do you need /api/ to your input express path?

```
app.post('/api/splunk_alert', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
     response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});
```

Refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.1/Alert/Webhooks for details of the contents of the web-hook.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand "Do you need /api/ to your input express path?"

Comment: In your original code, your route is `app.post('/splunk_alert'` , which will be equivalent to `http://hostname/splunk_alert`

I am suggesting you need to change the route to `app.post('/api/splunk_alert'`, which corresponds to your webhook URL, `http://hostname/api/splunk_alert`

Comment: Sorry for confusion. My post request is `app.post('/api/splunk_alert'`

Comment: OK, so what seems to be the problem? Are you sure the search is running -- check the raised alerts to verify that it is running. Check _internal logs to see if the alert action is working or not, is there a firewall blocking the request? Have you manually tried POSTing data to the endpoint, and do you get a response?